# Arduino UNO basics for C#

Tags: c#, arduino, microcontroller

Hello I am new to controlling hardware with a USB connection. I have an Arduino UNO Microcontroller and was searching for resources to get me started. I program in C# (Visual Studio 2010) and was wondering if there were some basics I could use to setting up/testing my connection. I'm looking for something as simple as a check box in my WinForm toggling the Digital I/O pin on the Arduino between high and low. Haven't been able to find much to start with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure you know that Arduino has a few samples that you can use with C#

[Here's their C# page](http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Csharp)

Comment: for some reason, my searching never got me that page. thanks.

Answer (score 13):

There are many ways to send a command from the pc to an arduino. Sandeep Bansil provides a good example of connecting and reading a serial port.

Below is a working example of how to write to a serial port based on the state of a checkbox on a windows form amd how to process the request from the pc on the arduino.

This is a verbose example, there are cleaner solutions but this is clearer.

In the example the arduino waits for either an 'a' or a 'b' from the pc. the pc sends an 'a' when a checkbox is checked and sends a 'b' when a checkbox is unchecked. The example assumes digital pin 4 on the arduino.

**Arduino code**

```
#define DIGI_PIN_SOMETHING 4
unit8_t commandIn;
void setup()
{
    //create a serial connection at 57500 baud
    Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop()
{
    //if we have some incomming serial data then..
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        //read 1 byte from the data sent by the pc
        commandIn = serial.read();
        //test if the pc sent an 'a' or 'b'
        switch (commandIn)
        {
            case 'a':
            {
                //we got an 'a' from the pc so turn on the digital pin
                digitalWrite(DIGI_PIN_SOMETHING,HIGH);
                break;
            }
            case 'b':
            {
                //we got an 'b' from the pc so turn off the digital pin
                digitalWrite(DIGI_PIN_SOMETHING,LOW);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Windows C#**

This code will reside in your form .cs file. The example assumes that you have attached form events for OnOpenForm, OnCloseForm and the OnClick event to the checkbox. From each of the events you can call the respective methods below....

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

class fooForm and normal stuff
{
    SerialPort port;

    private myFormClose()
    {
        if (port != null)
        port.close();
    }

    private myFormOpen()
    {
        port = new SerialPort("COM4", 57600);
        try
        {
            //un-comment this line to cause the arduino to re-boot when the serial connects
            //port.DtrEnabled = true;

            port.Open();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //alert the user that we could not connect to the serial port
        }
    }

    private void myCheckboxClicked()
    {
        if (myCheckbox.checked)
        {
            port.Write("a");
        } 
        else
        {  
            port.Write("b");    
        }
    }
}
```

Tip:

If you want to read a message from the arduino then add a timer to your form with an interval of `50` or `100` milliseconds.

In the `OnTick` event of the Timer you should check for data using the following code:

```
//this test is used to see if the arduino has sent any data
if ( port.BytesToRead > 0 )

//On the arduino you can send data like this 
Serial.println("Hellow World") 

//Then in C# you can use 
String myVar = port.ReadLine();
```

The result of `readLine()` will be that `myVar` contains `Hello World`.

Comment: Please create a new question with your code. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using Visual Studio, you might be interested in this cool Visual Studio plugin for Arduino development. http://www.visualmicro.com

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to communication between PC and Arduino is create 2 buttons On PC and turn ON/off the light on Arduino. Use `portwrite();`

Here's the simplest demo:
https://www.instructables.com/id/C-Serial-Communication-With-Arduino/
That's absolutely what you want!

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
namespace ledcontrol
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosed);
            if (port==null)
            {
                port = new SerialPort("COM7", 9600);//Set your board COM
                port.Open();
            }
        }
        void Form1_FormClosed(object sender,FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(port !=null &&port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PortWrite("1");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PortWrite("0");
        }
        private void PortWrite(string message)
        {
            port.Write(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Arduino sketch:

```
const int LedPin = 13;  
int ledState = 0;  

void setup()  
{   
  pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);  

  Serial.begin(9600);    
}  

void loop()  
{   
    char receiveVal;     

    if(Serial.available() > 0)  
    {          
        receiveVal = Serial.read();  

       if(receiveVal == '1')      
          ledState = 1;     
       else  
          ledState = 0;       
    }     

    digitalWrite(LedPin, ledState);   

    delay(50);      
}
```